# LINQ to SQL - Restrict Relationship by Condition (One to Many) (1 - M)

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

OK, first off, I'm brand new to LINQ2SQL so excuse my ignorance.

I've done some searches, but after 1 hour, I decided to come here.

Here goes:

I'm trying to do something that I think is very simple. It could just be that I don't understand. I'm using LINQ 2 SQL, via the VS designer. I have 2 tables: Clients and Categories. A client can have multiple categories.

I have a very simple query to find clients:

```
Client c = db.Clients.SingleOrDefault(client => client.ID == id);
```

What I want to do is modify this so that the collection: c.Categories, will only contain a subset of that client's categories.

This is what I've tried:

```
Client c = db.Categories.Where(cat => cat.IsActive == true).Select(cat.Clients).SingleOrDefault(client => client.ID == id);
```

I get an error reporting that more than one client is being returned.

1. Am I missing something? Is this not something that LINQ is designed to do?
2. Am I supposed to use the first query then do another query specifically on Categories when I need that list??

   c.Categories.Categories.Where(cat => cat.IsActive == true)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: how do you want to restrict the list of categories for a client? Is there e.g. a "IsActive (bool)" field on the categories table you wish to look at?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

SingleOrDefault() is for when there's ONLY one result. It seems like there's more than one record that has that id. Try using FirstOrDefault() instead.

```
Client c = db.Categories.Where(cat => cat.Name == "Name").Select(cat.Clients).FirstOrDefault(client => client.ID == id);
```

Comment: It compiles and runs, but the condition (cat.Name == "Name") is totally ignored.

Comment: OK, looking over your code, I'm actually confused as to what you're trying to accomplish. What exactly are you looking to do? Are you looking to delete records from the DB?

Comment: I just copied Marc's comment:
how do you want to restrict the list of categories for a client? Is there e.g. a "IsActive (bool)" field on the categories table you wish to look at? – marc_s 30 mins ago

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `Categories.Where` part in combination with the `Select`, is returning a collection of collections. What you may need to do is either use `SelectMany`, or use `Single` (or `SingleOrDefault`, or `First` or `FirstOrDefault`) instead of `Where`.

Examples:

```
Client c = db.Categories.Where(cat => cat.IsActive)
                        .SelectMany(cat.Clients)
                        .SingleOrDefault(client => client.ID == id);
```

or

```
Client c = db.Categories.Single(cat => cat.IsActive)
                        .Clients
                        .SingleOrDefault(client => client.ID == id);
```

Comment: The 2nd one isn't going to work. I need ALL categories with that Name...

May be name is a bad example...Let me modify my original question